# how to append month on flow while converting to different format

Tags: sql, oracle, date, oracle11g

In table there will be date as blow.

```
datecolumn         output should be  
2025                                 2025
202501                               202512(max month of that year)
202510
202512
2026                                 2026
202601 
202603                               202603(max month of that year)
2027                                 2027
```

actually my requirement is to partition based on the datecolumn and get the year with max month.
So when iam converting date column to get only in year format. iam getting the error

```
to_char(to_date(SVY_REF_PERIOD, 'yyyymm'), 'yyyy')

ORA-01840: input value not long enough for date format
01840. 00000 -  "input value not long enough for date format"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Only by above format i can partition the result set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
substr(datecolumn, 1, 4) ||
  case when length(datecolumn) = 6 
       then to_char(max(to_number(substr(datecolumn, -2)))  
                      over (partition by substr(datecolumn, 1, 4) || length(datecolumn)), 
                    'FM00') else null end
```

But I don't understand one thing:

```
datecolumn         output should be  
2025                                 2025
202501                               202512(max month of that year)
202510                               -- why here is NULL, not 202512?
202512
```

Comment: its not , i shown like that. If is use partition, rest of the data will not be displayed in result set

Comment: @developer Sorry, I didn't checked my first query. I had changed it, now it works.